# Calculation of the GINI coefficient,Accuracy and AUROC for credit scoring using Python code

Tags: python, cross-validation, excel, gini, credit-scoring

I have the following data and I want to compute the GINI and Accuracy for model validation purposes. But I tried to calculate the GINI and Accuracy using Python code, but it seems incorrect. I would like to compute the AUC, GINI and Accuracy by calculating the cumulative no of borrowers, cumulative no of goods, and cumulative no of bads.

Because I want to implement this in Microsoft excel and Python, hence trying to calculate but no success

Below are the codes:

```
# code 1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

data = {
  "Decile": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  "No. Borrowers": [100, 300, 200, 300, 600, 200, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
  "Good Borrowers": [80, 160, 140, 220, 500, 1000, 560, 640, 1500, 800],
  "Bad Borrowers": [20, 140, 60, 80, 1000 ,1000 ,1400 ,1600 ,7500 ,200]
}

good_borrowers = data['Good Borrowers']
bad_borrowers = data['Bad Borrowers']

total_borrowers = [good_borrowers[i] + bad_borrowers[i] for i in range(len(good_borrowers))]
cumulative_good_borrowers = [sum(good_borrowers[:i+1]) for i in range(len(good_borrowers))]
cumulative_bad_borrowers = [sum(bad_borrowers[:i+1]) for i in range(len(bad_borrowers))]

cumulative_good_borrower_ratio = [cumulative_good_borrowers[i]/total_borrowers[i] for i in range(len(total_borrowers))]
cumulative_bad_borrower_ratio = [cumulative_bad_borrowers[i]/total_borrowers[i] for i in range(len(total_borrowers))]

fpr,tpr,_ = roc_curve(data['Decile'], cumulative_good_borrower_ratio)
roc_auc = auc(fpr,tpr)
gini = (2 * roc_auc) -1

print("AUC: ", roc_auc)
print("GINI: ", gini)


#code 2: 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a data frame to store the number of borrowers, good borrowers, and bad borrowers in each decile.
data = {
  "Decile": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  "No. Borrowers": [100, 300, 200, 300, 600, 200, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
  "Good Borrowers": [80, 160, 140, 220, 500, 100, 560, 640, 150, 800],
  "Bad Borrowers": [20, 140, 60, 80, 100, 100, 140, 160, 750, 200]
}

# Calculate the ROC curve.
fpr = []
tpr = []
for decile in range(0, len(data["Decile"])):
    good_borrowers_in_decile = data["Good Borrowers"][decile]
    bad_borrowers_in_decile = data["Bad Borrowers"][decile]
    total_borrowers_in_decile = good_borrowers_in_decile + bad_borrowers_in_decile
    fpr.append(bad_borrowers_in_decile / total_borrowers_in_decile)
    tpr.append(good_borrowers_in_decile / total_borrowers_in_decile)

# Plot the ROC curve.
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
plt.title("ROC Curve")
plt.show()

# Calculate the AUC.
auc = np.trapz(tpr,fpr)
print("AUC:", auc)

# Calculate the accuracy.
accuracy = (sum(data["Good Borrowers"]) + sum(data["Bad Borrowers"])) / sum(data["No. Borrowers"])
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

# Calculate the Gini coefficient.
#gini = 1 - np.sum((np.array(data["No. Borrowers"]) * (np.array(data["No. Borrowers"]) -1))) / (np.prod(np.array(data["No. Borrowers"])) **2)
def gini(data):
    borrowers = np.array(data["No. Borrowers"])
    if 0 in borrowers:
        return None
    gini = 1 - np.sum((borrowers * (borrowers -1))) / (np.prod(borrowers) **2)
    return gini
gini(data)
print("Gini coefficient:", gini)
```

> Data:

| Decile | No. Borrowers | Good Borrowers | Bad Borrowers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 80 | 20 |
| 2 | 300 | 160 | 140 |
| 3 | 200 | 140 | 60 |
| 4 | 300 | 220 | 80 |
| 5 | 600 | 500 | 100 |
| 6 | 200 | 100 | 100 |
| 7 | 700 | 560 | 140 |
| 8 | 800 | 640 | 160 |
| 9 | 900 | 150 | 750 |
| 10 | 1000 | 800 | 200 |

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you only have summary data (not the full dataset) then the scikit-learn metrics package will not work as expected. I found [this useful blog](https://kiwidamien.github.io/what-is-a-roc-curve-a-visualization-with-credit-scores.html) that I think may help you understand how that function works. The blog uses an example very similar to your question.

Also, I need 50 creds to write comments on posts, so I wasn't able to ask for clarification. However, based on your data, it seems that you are trying to calculate the fpr and tpr of a good/bad borrower classifier. My interpretation is that the "No. Borrowers" column is the number of borrowers classified as good borrowers by the model given that you use a threshold of selecting the top $i^{th}$ decile, while the other two columns are the true number of good and bad borrowers at that decile.

If that is the case, then we must make a few corrections to the code. Remember that $FPR = \frac{FP}{FP + TN}$ therefore at a given threshold we must divide the total number of accepted bad borrowers (the cumulative sum until the $i^{th}$ threshold) and divide by the total number of bad borrowers.

similarly, the tpr may be computed using the formula: $TPR = \frac{TP}{TP + FN}$

Your accuracy can be calculated with the following formula $Acc = \frac{TP + TN}{Total\_population}$. In other words, your accepted positives (cumulative sum of good borrowers until $i^{th}$ threshold), plus your denied negatives (sum of bad borrowers beyond $i^{th}$ threshold), divided by you total number of borrowers.

Here is my implementation of your code. I will ignore code #1 since I believe code #2 is closer to a good answer. I have also taken the liberty to make the code a bit cleaner by using more built-in tools from numpy and pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a data frame to store the number of borrowers, good borrowers, and bad borrowers in each decile.
data = {
  "Decile": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  "No. Borrowers": [100, 300, 200, 300, 600, 200, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
  "Good Borrowers": [80, 160, 140, 220, 500, 100, 560, 640, 150, 800],
  "Bad Borrowers": [20, 140, 60, 80, 100, 100, 140, 160, 750, 200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

total_population = df['No. Borrowers'].sum()
df['TP'] = df['Good Borrowers'].cumsum()
df['FN'] = df['Good Borrowers'].sum() - df['Good Borrowers'].cumsum()
df['FP'] = df['Bad Borrowers'].cumsum()
df['TN'] = df['Bad Borrowers'].sum() - df['Bad Borrowers'].cumsum()

df['fpr'] = df.FP / (df.FP + df.TN)
df['tpr'] = df.TP / (df.TP + df.FN)
df['acc'] = (df.TP + df.TN) / total_population

# Calculate the AUC.
auc = np.trapz(df.tpr,df.fpr)
print("AUC:", auc)

# Calculate the Gini coefficient.
gini = 2*auc - 1
print("Gini coefficient:", gini)

# Plot the ROC curve.
plt.plot(df.fpr, df.tpr)
plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
plt.title("ROC Curve")
plt.fill_between(df.fpr, df.tpr, alpha = 0.1)
plt.text(0.6, 0.4, f'AUC = {auc:0.3}\n Gini = {gini:0.3}')
plt.show()
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification. I am pretty new to StackExchange so I'm still getting used to this type of communication skill :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, "No. Borrowers" column is the number of borrowers approved for the loan facility, while the all borrowers gets score at the time of loan approval, lower scores are at lower decile and higher scores are at higher decile. Score can range from 300 to 900. 300 will be at decile 1 and 900 at decile 10

Comment: I tried to match this code with the method elaborated in this link, i am not sure why it does not match the output with this link : https://www.listendata.com/2019/09/gini-cumulative-accuracy-profile-auc.html